# Maxindex in FixedWindowrollingpolicy

Tags: java, apache, log4j

I want to know what if maxindex reached in case of FixedwindowRollingPolicy.
where it writes the logs.

I am using it and given the maxindex as 10. once it reaches 10. i am not able to find the logs where it is writing?

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the class [`org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/FixedWindowRollingPolicy.html), the files are deleted. They are not written anywhere else.

> Let *max* and *min* represent the values of respectively the **MaxIndex** and **MinIndex** options. Let "foo.log" be the value of the **ActiveFile** option and "foo.%i.log" the value of **FileNamePattern**. Then, when rolling over, the file `foo.max.log` will be deleted, the file `foo.max-1.log` will be renamed as `foo.max.log`, the file `foo.max-2.log` renamed as `foo.max-1.log`, and so on, the file `foo.min+1.log` renamed as `foo.min+2.log`. Lastly, the active file `foo.log` will be renamed as `foo.min.log` and a new active file name `foo.log` will be created.